# Actualizar solo si hay cambios ajax php

Tags: php, sql, busqueda

Estoy teniendo un problema, más que con el código, con no saber como hacer la lógica jaja

Comento lo que quiero hacer: Necesito que en pantalla siempre este un registro de la base de datos activo y por atras busco si tengo en la base de datos un registro posterior a mostrar.

Digamos que son 3 registros con un hora y cada uno definida.

```
registro 1: hora=20:50
registro 2: hora=20:54
registro 3: hora=21:15
```

En pantalla tendría que quedar el registro 1 hasta que la hora actual sea las 20:54, donde automáticamente cambiaría al registro 2, siendo este el que queda en pantalla hasta que llegue la hora de mostrar el registro 3, el cual va a quedar hasta que vuelva a llegar la hora del registro 1. No se si se entiende bien jajja

Dejo los códigos de los archivos que hice

index.php

```
<div id="screen"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
$("#screen").load('buscar.php')
}, 30000);
});
</script>
```

buscar.php

```
$hora = date("H:i");

$sql_buscar = "SELECT * FROM contenido_reservas where hora_actual like '$hora%'";
$res_buscar = mysqli_query($link, $sql_buscar);
while ($row_buscar = mysqli_fetch_array($res_buscar)) {

  echo "<p>" . $row_buscar['datos_nombre'] . "</p>";
}
```

El código funciona pero el problema es que cuando pasa la hora justa, se va de pantalla la consulta, obviamente, y no carga mas nada hasta que llega la próxima hora de carga.

He probado metiendo la hora en una variable de session y varias cosas pero no le encuentro la vuelta como para que quede en pantalla mientras espera el próximo registro en su hora para cargar.

Aclaraciones:
**¿De dónde vienen los tres valores iniciales?**
Los valores vienen de una base de datos mysql, la cual se modifica algunas veces y se actualizan los horarios

**¿Se trata de horas fijas (son siempre esas horas, o pueden ser
otras)?**
Las horas la trae de los registros, al modificar los registros se actualizan las horas en la tabla

**¿Qué criterio define las diferencias para filtrar en el WHERE
de la consulta SQL?**
El where solamente filtra los registros por el horario el cual nunca se repetiría. Al filtrar luego en la consulta yo genero la tabla con los datos a mostrar que tiene ese registros, como ser nombre, consultorio, etc..

Esper alguien me pueda dar una mano con esta lógica
Gracias

Comment: Faltan detalles en tu pregunta. ¿De dónde vienen los tres valores iniciales? ¿Se trata de horas fijas (son siempre esas horas, o pueden ser otras)? ¿Qué criterio define las diferencias para filtrar en el `WHERE` de la consulta SQL? Considera que la zona chorar puede ser una en el cliente (Javascript) y otra en el servidor (PHP/Base de datos). Pulsa en [edit] y completa tu pregunta explicando con toda claridad y sencillez el contexto.

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato es `hora_actual`?

Comment: Es de tipo date y contiene la hora en que se tiene que mostrar el registro

Comment: En el tipo DATE no puedes guardar horas.

Comment: perdon es TIME, es que tengo los dos campos el de dia y hora. 
El problema lo tengo con el de hora que es el que tengo que hacer la comprobación